# How to create a Thread in RubyMotion for Android

Tags: java, android, ruby, rubymotion

Im trying to create a thread in RubyMotion for Android (beta).

I have tried the following code:

```
class MyRun
  def run
  end
end

r = MyRun.new
t = Thread.new(r)
t.start
```

The error I get is:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='< init>' signature='(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V' in class Lcom/rubymotion/Thread;`

It is automatically finding the right signature (Runnable) but Im not sure why its confused.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/Thread.html

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Thread.html

Comment: were you able to solve this? I'm stuck in something similar with rubymotion  on android

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
t = Thread.new do
  r.run  
end
# Don't need to explicitly start, the thread will start automatically by the thread scheduler.
# t.start
```

Ruby's `Thread.new` needs a block. Any arguments passed to `.new` will get passed into the block:

```
Thread.new('some value') do |arg1|
  arg1 # => "some value"
end
```

The docs you linked to are Java's API not Ruby's.

Comment: I am using RubyMotion, see: http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/api/Thread.html After using your answer I am still getting the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='<init>' signature='()V' in class Lcom/rubymotion/Thread;

Comment: @diego.greyrobot what should we prefer using? 1) Ruby threads or 2) AsyncTask? ---> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: What AsyncTask lib do you refer to?